# extend a concrete instance of a generic type in Swift

Tags: swift, generics

Is it possible to provide an extension that only applies to a specific instance of a generic type?

For example, say I want to add a method to `Int?`, but not to any other `Optional`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Just extend Int itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of. Since `Optional` is a protocol, you can create an extension and constrain it. However, the constraint can't be on a type, but needs to be on a protocol.

This works:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: SignedIntegerType {
    func test() -> Int {
        return 0
    }
}
```

and then you can use it:

```
let a:Int? = nil
a.test()
```

However, if you try to do:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: Int {
    func test() -> Int {
        return 0
    }
}
```

you'll get an error:

> type 'Wrapped' constrained to non-protocol type 'Int'

Comment: Note that when calling that method you have to call it as it were non optional.

Comment: Yes, which makes it look weird, IMHO.